# spring cloud sleuth - frequency sending traces to opentelemetry collector

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cloud-sleuth

I setup spring boot tracing following this tutorial https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-opentelemetry-setup and got the traces sent to the opentelemetry collector endpoint I set as property. Now I have 2 questions I couldn't answer reading the doc:

- Is the export call to the collector endpoint synchronous?
- Is it possible to configure the frequency of this call? Something like sending traces in batches every given interval? I see there are properties about "batch" in https://spring-projects-experimental.github.io/spring-cloud-sleuth-otel/docs/current/reference/html/appendix.html but couldn't find any example

Thanks